# White Screen on form post

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, post

I am having a white screen of death appear when a user post a form that I made. Interesting thing is when I as the admin of the site (this site is run using wordpress) post the same data in the form and submit it works, but when a user does it does the white screen, and help. Below is the form data and some other code I am using.

Here is the code that is for the form part (I know it is not great code I am still learning)

```
    function bio_form(){
global $wpdb, $current_user;

//get current user info
get_currentuserinfo();  

$yes = $_GET['submitted'];

//check log in
if(!is_user_logged_in()) {  
    //user isnt logged in
    echo "You must be logged in to use this form";
    //show login form
    if (!(current_user_can('level_0'))){
        echo "<h2>Login</h2>";
        echo "<form action=" . get_option('home') . "/wp-login.php method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
        echo "<input type='text' name='log' id='log' value='" . wp_specialchars(stripslashes($user_login), 1) . "' size='20' />";
        echo "<input type='password' name='pwd' id='pwd' size='20' />";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Send' class='button' />";
        echo "<p>";
        echo "<label for='rememberme'><input name='rememberme' id='rememberme' type='checkbox' checked='checked' value='forever' /> Remember me</label>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='redirect_to' value=" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . " />";
        echo "</p>";
        echo "</form>";
        echo "<a href='" . get_option('home') . "/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword'>Recover password</a>";
        //add register link
    } else { 
        echo "<h2>Logout</h2>";
        echo "<a href=" . wp_logout_url(urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) . ">logout</a><br />";
    }   
}else{
    $gg = false;
    if($yes == NULL){
        $id = $_GET['enID'];
        $em = $_GET['em'];
        $sub = $_GET['submit'];
        if($id == NULL || $em == NULL){     
            echo "<div align='center'><form action=''>";
            echo "<p>Plese use the email you used on the your entry, and the entryID that was generated for your entry.</p>";
            echo "Email: <input type='text' name='em' value='$em'></input></br>";
            echo "EntryID: <input type='text' name='enID' value='$id'></input></br>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='submit' value='yes'></input>";
            echo "<input type='submit' value='submit'></input></form></div>";
    }else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `" . WP_BIO_GIRLS_DATA . "`"; 
        $users = $wpdb->get_results($sql);  
        foreach($users as $user){
            if(($user->id == $id)&& ($user->email == $em)){
                $gg = true;
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
}else{
    $gg = true;
}

    if($gg == true){
        //user is logged in
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `" . WP_BIO_GIRLS . "`";  
        $users = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

        //Check to see if user is in GG DB
        $userThere = false;

        foreach($users as $user){
            if($user->user_id == $current_user->ID){    
                $userThere = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        //If not in GG DB add to it
        if($userThere == false){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `" . WP_BIO_GIRLS . "` (user_id,title1,title2,title3,title4,title5,title6,title7,title8,title9,title10,title11,title12,title13,title14,title15) VALUES ($current_user->ID,'What game consoles (if any) do you own & which is your favorite?','What are your Gamertags & corresponding gamerscores for those consoles?','What are your top 3 games? Movies? Favorite Genre?','What nerd icon, hero, or villian do you have a crush on?','What was your first exposure to nerd culture?','What is your dream game?','What would be your ideal character to cosplay?','What do you feel makes nerd culture unique?','What do you feel nerd culture lacks?','How do you feel about professional Video Gaming?','What superpower would you have and would  / should you register it?','What is the worst pick up line you have ever heard?','Do you find Murdoc (our mascot) sexy?','How many hours a day would you say you spend nerding out?','How do you envision D-day coming about?')";
            $insert = $wpdb->query($sql);
        }

        //Place to get post and store data
        $fName = $_GET['firstname'];
        $lName = $_GET['lastname'];
        $email = $_GET['email']);
        $dName = $_GET['disname'];
        $enID = $_GET['eid'];
        $Q1 = $_GET['Q1'];
        $Q2 = $_GET['Q2'];
        $Q3 = $_GET['Q3'];
        $Q4 = $_GET['Q4'];
        $Q5 = $_GET['Q5'];
        $Q6 = $_GET['Q6'];
        $Q7 = $_GET['Q7'];
        $Q8 = $_GET['Q8'];
        $Q9 = $_GET['Q9'];
        $Q10 = $_GET['Q10'];
        $Q11 = $_GET['Q11'];
        $Q12 = $_GET['Q12'];
        $Q13 = $_GET['Q13'];
        $Q14 = $_GET['Q14'];
        $Q15 = $_GET['Q15'];


    if($dName != NULL && $email != NULL && $lName != NULL && $fName != NULL && $enID != NULL && ($_GET['submitted'] != NULL)){  
        //Call entry id db to see if they are a GG.
        echo "<div align='center'>Information was saved!!</div>";

        //Store database
        $sql = "UPDATE `" . WP_BIO_GIRLS . "` SET FirstName='$fName', LastName='$lName', Email='$email', DisName='$dName', EID='$enID', text1='$Q1', text2='$Q2', text3='$Q3', text4='$Q4', text5='$Q5', text6='$Q6', text7='$Q7', text8='$Q8', text9='$Q9', text10='$Q10', text11='$Q11', text12='$Q12', text13='$Q13', text14='$Q14', text15='$Q15' WHERE user_id='$current_user->ID'";
        $stored = $wpdb->query($sql);   

    }else{
        //Need to fill required fields
        if(($fName == NULL || $lName == NULL || $email == NULL || $dName == NULL || $enID == NULL) && ($_GET['submitted'] != NULL)){
            echo "<div align='center'><style>h2 {color:#FF0000;}</style><h2>Please fill out all the required boxes</h2></div>"; 
    }
        //Old, needs deleted
        $status = false;    

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `" . WP_BIO_GIRLS . "`";  
        $users = $wpdb->get_results($sql);      

        foreach($users as $user){       
            if($user->user_id == $current_user->ID){            
                $status = true;                         
                break;      
            }   
        }   

        if($status == false){       
            echo "<div align='center'><h3>Sorry only gamer girls can fill out this form</h3></div>";
        }else{
            //Show form if all checks pass

            //get current users current values
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `" . WP_BIO_GIRLS . "` WHERE user_id='$current_user->ID'";    
            $users = $wpdb->get_results($sql);      

            //get values from db
            foreach($users as $user){
                $userID = $user->user_id;
                $fName = $user->FirstName;
                $lName = $user->LastName;
                $dName = $user->DisName;
                $email = $user->Email;
                $EID = $user->EID;
                $userQ1T = $user->title1;
                $userQ1X = $user->text1;
                $userQ2T = $user->title2;
                $userQ2X = $user->text2;
                $userQ3T = $user->title3;
                $userQ3X = $user->text3;
                $userQ4T = $user->title4;
                $userQ4X = $user->text4;
                $userQ5T = $user->title5;
                $userQ5X = $user->text5;
                $userQ6T = $user->title6;
                $userQ6X = $user->text6;
                $userQ7T = $user->title7;
                $userQ7X = $user->text7;
                $userQ8T = $user->title8;
                $userQ8X = $user->text8;
                $userQ9T = $user->title9;
                $userQ9X = $user->text9;
                $userQ10T = $user->title10;
                $userQ10X = $user->text10;
                $userQ11T = $user->title11;
                $userQ11X = $user->text11;
                $userQ12T = $user->title12;
                $userQ12X = $user->text12;
                $userQ13T = $user->title13;
                $userQ13X = $user->text13;
                $userQ14T = $user->title14;
                $userQ14X = $user->text14;
                $userQ15T = $user->title15;
                $userQ15X = $user->text15;
            }
            //create form
            echo "<style>textarea {resize:none;} table {text-align: center;}</style>";      
            echo "<div align='center' id='form'><h1>Gaming Girls Information Form</h1>";
            echo "<h7>* denoted required fields</h7>";
            echo "<table cellspacing='20' cellpadding='3'>";
            echo "<tr><td><form name='info_form' action='' method='get' ENCTYPE='multipart/form-data'></td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>*First Name: <input type='text' name='firstname' value='$fName'></input></td></tr>";  
            echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>*Last Name: <input type='text' name='lastname' value='$lName'></input></td></tr>";    
            echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>*Display Name: <input type='text' name='disname' value='$dName'></input></td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>*Email: <input type='text' name='email' value='$email'></input></td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td colspan='2'>*OHMS Gaming EntryID: <input type='text' name='eid' value='$EID'></input></td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>$userQ1T : <TEXTAREA rows='3' cols='30' name='Q1'>$userQ1X</TEXTAREA></td>";  
            echo "<td>$userQ2T : <TEXTAREA rows='3' cols='30' name='Q2'>$userQ2X</TEXTAREA></td></tr>"; 
            echo "<tr><td>$userQ3T : <TEXTAREA rows='3' cols='30' name='Q3'>$userQ3X</TEXTAREA></td>";              
            echo "<td>$userQ4T : <TEXTAREA rows='3' cols='30' name='Q4'>$userQ4X</TEXTAREA></td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>$userQ5T : <TEXTAREA rows='3' cols='30' name='Q5'>$userQ5X</TEXTAREA></td>";
            echo "<td>$userQ6T : <TEXTAREA rows='3' cols='30' name='Q6'>$userQ6X</TEXTAREA></td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>$userQ7T : <TEXTAREA rows='3' cols='30' name='Q7'>$userQ7X</TEXTAREA></td>";
            echo "<td>$userQ8T : <TEXTAREA rows='3' cols='30' name='Q8'>$userQ8X</TEXTAREA></td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>$userQ9T : <TEXTAREA rows='3' cols='30' name='Q9'>$userQ9X</TEXTAREA></td>";
            echo "<td>$userQ10T : <TEXTAREA rows='3' cols='30' name='Q10'>$userQ10X</TEXTAREA></td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>$userQ11T : <TEXTAREA rows='3' cols='30' name='Q11'>$userQ11X</TEXTAREA></td>";
            echo "<td>$userQ12T : <TEXTAREA rows='3' cols='30' name='Q12'>$userQ12X</TEXTAREA></td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>$userQ13T : <TEXTAREA rows='3' cols='30' name='Q13'>$userQ13X</TEXTAREA></td>";
            echo "<td>$userQ14T : <TEXTAREA rows='3' cols='30' name='Q14'>$userQ14X</TEXTAREA></td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>$userQ15T : <TEXTAREA rows='3' cols='30' name='Q15'>$userQ15X</TEXTAREA></td></tr>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' value='yes' name='submitted'></input>";      
            echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><input type='submit' value='Submit'></input></td></tr>";      
            echo "</form></table></div>";
            }
        }
    }else{
        if($sub == true){
            echo "<div align='center'><h1>Not a vaild id</h1></div>";
        }
    }
}
}
```

If anyone can help here that would be great. I am wondering if it has to do with the post data, for instance, This is a sample of the url when the form is submitted.

```
http://ohmsgaming.com/gaming-girls/gaming-girls-form/?firstname=Lilith&lastname=Crimson&disname=Lilith+Crimson&email=laceylynn325%40yahoo.com&eid=18301743&Q1=Sega+Genesis%2C+Super+Nintendo-2%2C+Nintendo-+2%2C+PlayStation+1%2C+Game+cube%2C+Gameboy%2C+Gameboy+Color%2C+Gameboy+Advanced%2C+Gameboy+SP%2C+Nintendo+64%2C+Xbox+360.&Q2=N%2FA&Q3=Games-%0D%0A1.+Battle+Toads%0D%0A2.+Elder+Scrolls%0D%0A3.+tales+of+symphonia%0D%0A%0D%0AMovies-%0D%0A1.+Labyrinth%0D%0A2.+Strangeland%0D%0A3.+Ace+Ventura+2%0D%0A%0D%0AGenre%0D%0AScifi&Q4=Anthony+Edward+Stark+%28Tony+Stark%2C+Iron+Man%29&Q5=My+Eldest+Brother+and+his+friends+playing+D%26D+and+Magic+the+Gathering+back+in+the+90%27s&Q6=Not+sure+what+you+mean+by+that%2C+but+Skyriim+at+the+Moment.+%0D%0A%0D%0AIf+I+could+create+one%3F+%0D%0A%0D%0AOne+that+takes+place+in+all+time+periods%2C+larger+then+Elder+Scrolls%2C+Being+able+to+create+your+own+fashions+Vastly%2C+weapons%2C+creatures%2C+looks%2C+Kinect+probably+could+take+a+self+scan+and+place+you+into+that+world+and+allow+you+to+live+the+world%2C+as+if+its+your+own+world.&Q7=Poison+Ivy%2C+or+Black+Widow..or+maybe+Red+Sonja.+Really+just+redheaded.+&Q8=The+Ability+to+see+past+reality+and+create+Their+own+Universal+Dimension+if+you+can+say%2C+and+expand+our+minds+into+thinking+%22What+if%22.+%0D%0A%0D%0AThe+nerds+mind+have+been+ubiquitous%2C+and+created+a+vast+reality+of+our+own%2C+making+life%2C+easier+for+some%2C+and+much+more+fun+for+others%2C+and+all+really.+%0D%0A%0D%0ATo+be+a+nerd%2C+isn%27t+just+about+having+brains+anymore%2C+Its+about+having+fun+and+bringing+a+new+level+of+reality+to+all+who+wishes+to+hear+it.&Q9=Pizza.+&Q10=I+think+its+a+great+idea.+Video+gaming+is+a+sport+%28in+its+own+way%29%2C+and+it+allows+gamers+to+pick+up+their+game+and+improve+their+abilities+and+others+learn.+Challenging+skills+allow+those+to+really+see%2C+who+can+kick+A**+and+who+just+need+to+go+home+and+continue+playing+Halo+with+their+friends+at+parties.&Q11=Flying%2FControl+of+Elements+%28really+that+would+be+considered+air%29.+No.+Where+is+the+fun+in+that%3F&Q12=-Hey+girl%2C+what%E2%80%99s+up%3F+Guess+what%3F+It%E2%80%99s+your+lucky+day.+Out+of+all+the+girls+here%2C+I+picked+you+to+talk+to-&Q13=In+a+Sense%2C+yes.+He%27s+very+Attractive.+I+want+to+hug+him+and+feed+him+Cheese+Lol&Q14=Probably+all+day..My+teacher+is+a+huge+nerd%2C+and+all+we+talk+about+is+video+games.+Yes%2C+she%27s+65.+%0D%0A%0D%0AThen+I+come+home%2C+and+pop+in+whatever+game+we+were+talking+about+all+day%2C+or+Oblivion.+Then+spend+the+rest+on+here+on+Deviant+Art+talking+about+Marvel%2C+DC%2C+and+Dark+Horse+Comics%2C+along+with+others.+%0D%0A%0D%0AAlso+D%26D+with+Magic+the+Gathering+with+one+of+my+young+friends+who+is+obsessed+with+them+and+needs+me+to+guide+them+Lol.+So+its+actually+kind+of+forced+sometimes&Q15=Nuclear+Apocalypse%2C+Zombies+then+Follow!&submitted=yes
```

It is really long, and there is many things in it, I am wondering if that is the issue, though as I said when I use the same above string it works fine for me when I am logged in as an admin.

P.S sorry that code didn't format well in the code block.

Comment: First, do a "view source" to see if something was output, but it's something that only renders a blank page.  Second, you need to look in the error log for your web server.  There's likely a message there telling you about some problem in that page.

Comment: I have looked at the error log, there is nothing. And there is no source, I believe it has to do with the %27 etc codes in the query

Comment: I fixed it by changing the method of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White screen usually means crash because of error. I recommend try search error by adding to php code line:

> print_r(error_get_last());

Error not be printed if error occurs bellow this line.

Also do not forget check if no error return from database (mysql, mysqli, PDO.. using different functions to get error).

Comment: I added that line of code but I dont see it printing anything anywhere, and the line is at the top of the function

Comment: Try add print_r(error_get_last()); in bottom of your php code

Comment: I get an error code but nothing to do with the form, for something else, and undefined var in another function.

Comment: Try add this line also where form data going to. You said that problems occurs when data submitted. So check errors on php file which handle submitted data.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the method of the form

Answer (score 1):

White screen is usually server 500 error but the notices if any are not output to the browser.

In your wp-config.php set debug to true:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Then log out flush your cache, clear your cookies then try to submit the form as a regular users and you will get the error messages.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the method of the form